# Control file based attribute population : Unix shell

Tags: unix, awk, scripting, cut

I have a control file header.cntrl. it has details of header. Example below...

```
cat header.cntrl
id, name, age, location, phone number
```

Now I am getting files from different sources,

Source 1 is sending input.dat file in the following format

```
cat input.dat
id, name, age, location, status, phone number
1,Abc, 34,India, active, 9999999999
```

Source 2 is sending data in the following format

```
cat input_2.dat
id, age, name, qualification, status, phone number, location
2,24,xyz, L L B, Active, 88888-88888, India
```

So different sources are sending files in different formats. We would need to convert those input files to header.cntrl file format.

I was trying this using awk code, but for each source, I'll need to write an awk code.  Can we do it with a single script which can be used for any new future source as well?

Comment: Is the input as capricious in its spacing after commas as shown in your sample data?  Or is there always space after the commas, or never space after the commas?

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case you can check the number of fields in lines (provided that all lines of a file have the same number of fields) (awk code):

```
{
  n = split($0, a, "[ \t]*,[ \t]*");
  if (n < 7) {
     print a[1] ", " a[2] ", " a[3] ", " a[4] ", " a[6];
  }
  else {
     print a[1] ", " a[3] ", " a[2] ", " a[7] ", " a[6];
  }
}
```

A more sophisticated solution is to use the first line as key identifier and take remaining fields "by name":

```
{
  n = split($0, a, "[ \t]*,[ \t]*");
  if (FNR == 1) {
     for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        lbl[a[i]] = i;
     }
  }
  
  print a[lbl["id"]] ", " a[lbl["name"]] ", " a[lbl["age"]] ", " a[lbl["location"]] ", " a[lbl["phone number"]];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This `reformat_data` script can reformat the two "non-standard" input formats and any future source formats. The key idea is to use Perl hashes to store the appropriate headings and only print those that are needed as specified in the header.cntrl file.

```
cat $* | perl -ne '
BEGIN {
  @std_header = ("id","name","age","location","phone number");
  print join(",", @std_header), ",\n";
  chomp($firstline=<>);
  $firstline =~ s/,\s+/,/g;
  @inputfile_header=split(/,/, $firstline);
  %hash=();
}

chomp;
@row = split(/,/);
$i=0;

for $cell (@row) {
   $cell =~ s/\s+//;
   $header=$inputfile_header[$i];
   $hash{$header} = $row[$i];
   $i++;
}

foreach $cell (@std_header) {
   print "$hash{$cell},";
}
print "\n";
'
```

Here are the results of running the `reformat_data` script using the two sample input files:

```
cat input.dat
id, name, age, location, status, phone number
1,Abc, 34,India, active, 9999999999

reformat_data input.dat
id,name,age,location,phone number,
1,Abc,34,India,9999999999,

cat input_2.dat
id, age, name, qualification, status, phone number, location
2,24,xyz, L L B, Active, 88888-88888, India

reformat_data input_2.dat
id,name,age,location,phone number,
2,xyz,24,India,88888-88888,
```